# Account Manager Caching Android

Tags: android, caching, accountmanager

Hello Everyone,
                      I have to create a custom account in Android that will be integrated with Account and Sync framework.
                      By default Account Manager caches the Auth token and returns the same for all request.
                      Is there any way to change this default behavior, I do not want Account Manager to cache the token.
                      Any info will be of great help.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to call [AccountManager.invalidateToken](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/accounts/AccountManager.html#invalidateAuthToken%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) each time you want to invalidate a given cached auth token.